# How to pass return value from Apex Controller method to visualforce page using actionFunction

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a situation where I need to return a value from Apex class controller, but most of the solution that I have seen on forums is to keep a variable globally and put the value to be returned in that variable and then get its value on oncomplete of actionFunction.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly pass a return value. Instead you would set a non-transient variable in the controller and then re-render a component on the page that displays that variable with it's new value. You can use this in JS as well so that you can run a script after re-rendering using the new value.

If you provide an example of what you need I can provide some code but this is too generic as it is for me to provide a meaningful example.

### Update

Here's a generic sample anyway:

```
public class controllerSample {
    public String returnValue {get; set;}

    public void action() {
        returnValue = 'Ta-Da';
    }
}
```

Page

```
<apex:outputPanel id="renderTarget">
    <script>
        if ('{!returnValue}' != 'null') {
            alert('{!returnValue}');
        }
    </script>

    <apex:commandButton action="{!action}" value="Do It" rerender="renderTarget"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: what will happen if I update this non transient variable from 2 different machines, logged in to same org of salesforce, won't they override each others result?

Comment: No, the controller is instantiated one per person so they each have their own non-transient variables. If you were trying to store this information in a record in the database then it would absolutely appear on both pages so... don't do that.

Comment: What if 2 machines are logged in using same credentials?

Comment: Still wont matter. They each have their own instance

Comment: If you post a question asking about VF view states and how they are able to keep information isolated I would be happy to answer that one too. I think there are people who might benefit from that information.

Comment: Sure, posting it right now as I will also be benefitted

Comment: Also, don't forget to acept the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83144/discussion-between-rrc1709-and-gnerb).